# undefined method error with a form check_box helper

Tags: checkbox, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I got an error with my check_box helper and don't understand what I am doing wrong :

```
undefined method `prive' for #<PubContributeur:0xa63b8fc>
```

This my **app/models/pub_contributeur.rb** :

```
class PubContributeur < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :nom, :prive
  validates :nom, :presence => true
  validates :nom, :length => { :in => 2..30 }, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

end
```

I'm using a namespace **catalogs** on my controller.
This is my HAML like view **app/views/catalogs/pub_contributeurs/_form.html.haml** :

```
= form_for [:catalogs, @pub_contributeur], :html => {:class => "formulaire-standard"} do |f|

  = render :partial => 'shared/error_message', :locals => { :element => @pub_contributeur, :debut_erreur => 'Ce contributeur ne peut être enregistré'}

  .groupe-champs
    .champ
      = f.label :nom
      = f.text_field :nom, :class => 'input-width-8-col', :required => 'required'
    .champ
      = f.label :prive
      = f.check_box :prive
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !

When I replace the

```
 = f.check_box :prive
```

line in my _form.rb with a debug on my instance variable :

```
= debug @pub_container
```

I can see something strange :

```
--- !ruby/object:PubContributeur
attributes:
  id: 
  nom: 
  description: 
  created_at: 
  updated_at:
```

I did check my db/migration/  and found the issue.
My migration file was creating a string field called "**description**" instead of a boolean field called "**prive**".

If we think a bit about the first error message. This is very weird because the class in the model file do have a "prive" accessible attribut that may mislead us to think the class do have "**nom**" and "**prive**" as attibuts.

To understand what is happening we must have an advanced knowledge about Rails and Ruby. This comes from the inheritance of **ActiveRecord::Base**.
The magic of Rails behind the scene creates attributes for the PubContributeur Class based on the name of the columns in the table pub_contributeurs of my DB.

I wish Rails error message could have been a bit more explicit ^^